# How to modify QJsonObject

Tags: c++, qt, qjson, qjsonobject

I can set values to objects this way in the simple json-file.

Qt code:

```
if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
    QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(file.readAll());
    QJsonObject obj = doc.object();
    obj["gender"] = "female";
    doc.setObject(obj);
    manager.put(request, doc.toJson());
}
```

Simple json file:

```
{
    "resourceType": "Patient",
    "gender": "male",
    "birthDate": "2018-08-21"
}
```

So this code changes the value of gender to female.

But when I use bigger json where there are "objects under objects"

```
{
    "resource": {
        "resourceType": "Patient",
        "id": "530f8eb0-1f0b-41b0-b94",
        "text": {
            "status": "generated",
            "div": "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">Teppo Testman\n            <a name=\"mm\"></a>\n          </div>"
        },
        "name": [{
            "family": "Testman",
            "given": [
                "Teppo"
            ]
        }],
        "gender": "male",
        "birthDate": "1993-02-12"
    }
}
```

Update:

```
{
    "resourceType": "Bundle",
    "id": "17772d63-3b14-494f-8182-06b67c970550",
    "meta": {
        "versionId": "1",
        "lastUpdated": "2018-08-15T12:08:48.036+00:00"
    },
    "type": "collection",
    "entry": [{
            "resource": {
                "resourceType": "Observation",
                "text": {
                    "status": "generated",
                    "div": "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">Height\n            <a name=\"mm\"></a>\n          </div>"
                },
                "status": "final",
                "code": {
                    "coding": [{
                        "system": "http://loinc.org",
                        "code": "8302-2",
                        "display": "Body height"
                    }]
                },
                "subject": {
                    "reference": "Patient/530f8eb0-1f0b-41b0-b94b-c25a14656645"
                },
                "valueQuantity": {
                    "value": 166,
                    "unit": "cm"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "resource": {
                "resourceType": "Observation",
                "text": {
                    "status": "generated",
                    "div": "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">BMI\n            <a name=\"mm\"></a>\n          </div>"
                },
                "status": "final",
                "code": {
                    "coding": [{
                        "system": "http://loinc.org",
                        "code": "39156-5",
                        "display": "Body mass index (BMI) [Ratio]"
                    }]
                },
                "subject": {
                    "reference": "Patient/530f8eb0-1f0b-41b0-b94b-c25a14656645"
                },
                "valueString": "23"
            }
        },
        {
            "resource": {
                "resourceType": "Observation",
                "text": {
                    "status": "generated",
                    "div": "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">FEV1 [l]\n            <a name=\"mm\"></a>\n          </div>"
                },
                "status": "final",
                "code": {
                    "coding": [{
                        "system": "http://loinc.org",
                        "code": "18759-1",
                        "display": "Spirometry study"
                    }]
                },
                "subject": {
                    "reference": "Patient/530f8eb0-1f0b-41b0-b94b-c25a14656645"
                },
                "valueQuantity": {
                    "value": 2,
                    "unit": "l"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "resource": {
                "resourceType": "Observation",
                "text": {
                    "status": "generated",
                    "div": "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">FEV6 [l]\n            <a name=\"mm\"></a>\n          </div>"
                },
                "status": "final",
                "code": {
                    "coding": [{
                        "system": "http://loinc.org",
                        "code": "18759-1",
                        "display": "Spirometry study"
                    }]
                },
                "subject": {
                    "reference": "Patient/530f8eb0-1f0b-41b0-b94b-c25a14656645"
                },
                "valueQuantity": {
                    "value": 2.9,
                    "unit": "l"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "resource": {
                "resourceType": "Observation",
                "text": {
                    "status": "generated",
                    "div": "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">PEF [l/s]\n            <a name=\"mm\"></a>\n          </div>"
                },
                "status": "final",
                "code": {
                    "coding": [{
                        "system": "http://loinc.org",
                        "code": "18759-1",
                        "display": "Spirometry study"
                    }]
                },
                "subject": {
                    "reference": "Patient/530f8eb0-1f0b-41b0-b94b-c25a14656645"
                },
                "valueQuantity": {
                    "value": 6.5,
                    "unit": "l/s"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "resource": {
                "resourceType": "Patient",
                "id": "530f8eb0-1f0b-41b0-b94b-c25a14656645",
                "text": {
                    "status": "generated",
                    "div": "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">Teppo Testman\n            <a name=\"mm\"></a>\n          </div>"
                },
                "name": [{
                    "family": "Testman",
                    "given": [
                        "Teppo"
                    ]
                }],
                "gender": "male",
                "birthDate": "1993-02-12"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm not able to modify the value. Is there some simple way to do that? I have been trying to find the solution with no success!

Comment: Why did I modify the json? 
It is not right to do it without justification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

json is not a linear structure, so you have to look for it through the arbor of keys, in this case there is a `gender` is the children of `resource`, so first you will access `resource` and then `gender` as I show below:

```
if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
    QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(file.readAll());
    QJsonObject root = doc.object();
    QJsonObject res = root["resource"].toObject();
    res["gender"] = "female";
    root["resource"] = res;
    doc.setObject(root);
    //another code
    manager.put(request, doc.toJson());
}
```

Update:

The idea is the same, you can not access directly but you have to know the structure of the json. Although I have an observation, for example the items children of entry that is an array, the normal thing is that those children have the same structure but in your case the last one is different which is unusual.

```
if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
    QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(file.readAll());
    QJsonObject root = doc.object();
    QJsonArray entries = root["entry"].toArray();
    for(int i=0; i < entries.count(); i++){
        QJsonObject obj = entries[i].toObject();
        QJsonObject objs = obj["resource"].toObject();
        if(objs.contains("gender")){
            objs["gender"]= "female";
            obj["resource"] = objs;
            entries[i] = obj;
        }
    }
    root["entry"] = entries;
    doc.setObject(root);
    // another process
}
```

Comment: I bet your answer was correct but my question was not that great. I tried to give shorter example of json that I am actually working with at the moment. I edited longer version of json to my original post. I tried to solve that but I still have problem. Does it make problems when there are resource many times in json? So there are all the resource are children of entry. How to choose what resource to edit?

Comment: @Lauri You should not delete the above, what you should do is add as an update to your question because for example my answer would not make sense if you delete the above.

Comment: Got it! I'm sorry for that. Started to edit it back but You fixed that for me as well. Thanks!